# Rails - best_in_place not updating view until after reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, best-in-place

I'm pretty new at Ruby on Rails and I'm struggling with best_in_place
I'm using best_in_place to enable editing of data within a HTML table. I'm able to successfully enter data and hit enter for it to save. The new data  briefly shows in the table, but it soon reverts back to the previous value. If I reload the page the table will show the new, updated data. Does anyone have any suggestion how to make the updated data show straight away?

This is the code for my controller:

```
    class GamesController < ApplicationController
      def index
        @games = Game.all
      end

      def show
        @game = Game.find(params[:id])
        #render 'index'
      end

      def new
        @game = Game.new
      end

      def edit
        @game = Game.find(params[:id])
      end

      def create
        @game = Game.new(game_params)

        if @game.save
          redirect_to @game
        else
          render 'new'
        end
      end

      def update
        @game = Game.find(params[:id])

        if @game.update(game_params)
          redirect_to @game
        else
          render 'edit'
        end
      end

    def destroy
        @game = Game.find(params[:id])
          @game.destroy

            redirect_to games_path
            end

    private
      def game_params
        params.require(:game).permit(:number, :title, :weight, :owner, :borrower, :borrowed)
      end
    end
```

And this is the code for the view:

```
<h1>Listing games</h1>
<%= link_to 'New game', new_game_path, :class => "pure-button pure-button-primary"  %>
<p>
<table class="pure-table sortable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="110px">Number</th>
      <th width="300px" >Title</th>
      <th width="110px">Weight</th>
      <th width="110px">Owner</th>
      <th width="120px">Borrowed</th>
      <th width="140px">Borrowed by</th>
      <th class="sorttable_nosort">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
  <% @games.each do |game| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= best_in_place game, :number, :inner_class => "input_number" %></td>
      <td><%= best_in_place game, :title , :inner_class => "input_title" %></td>
      <td><%= best_in_place game, :weight, :inner_class => "input_weight" %></td>
      <td><%= best_in_place game, :owner, :inner_class => "input_owner" %></td>
    <td><%= best_in_place game, :borrowed, as: :checkbox, collection: {false: "No", true: "Yes"} %></td>
    <td><%= best_in_place game, :borrower, :inner_class => "input_borrower" %></td>


    <td><%= link_to 'Show', game_path(game) %> |
      <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_game_path(game) %> |
      <%= link_to 'Destroy', game_path(game),
      method: :delete,
      data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
</p>
</div>

<%= render 'grid_bottom' =%>
```

Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated!

Comment: please check in your firebug or chrome-console the network graph and check if the ajax calls are made. please post route and response. also pls post rails-server log for that specified request. thanks

Comment: Hi,
I can't see any Ajax calls being made. The only call I see when I update the data is a PUT that gets a 302 response.

Comment: The corresponding message in the Rails server logs is:

Started PUT "/games/5" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-14 14:50:01 +0200
Processing by GamesController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"game"=>{"number"=>"300"}, "authenticity_token"=>"QomjrfJXXAFYiPA6wZ87xni8IKVWAOM+tvMATyVxXJQkx6mY9eSobq+3J5jDe0XZRjVC74ax6XrgWtTCRzA0sA==", "id"=>"5"}
  Game Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "games".* FROM "games" WHERE "games"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:9000/games/5
Completed 302 Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)

Comment: so now you found the problem. no parameter was updated based on the request. you changed the number value to 300.  but the problem is somewhere into your controller (update method). first of all, that method needs to responde on ajax calls, otherwise its rendering a hole html-template as a response for the update call. thats unneccesary.  
for me, the request looks fine, the params are correct, everything should work nice, except that there isnt any kind of database update. maybe you have an validation error?

Comment: please change to following http://pastie.org/10350831 and post the server request in a pastie file

Comment: Thanks, Huan! Chaning the update controller seems to have done the trick! I change it to what you added in the pastie above and now everything seems to work a treat. :)

Comment: ill Write u a better Controller tonorrow

Comment: @huanson please post your comments as an answer.

Comment: @hunter stevens you mean the better controller?

Comment: @huanson Whichever code helped answer OP's question should be submitted as an answer post.

Comment: you can find it here http://pastie.org/10350831 i just wrote him a new controller. the first one is his, the second is mine. maybe thats helping you too